# How to change Linux file attributes

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, file-access, file-attributes

I am working in C not in CPP and want to change the attributes of a executable file to hidden, read only, executable. I also want to change file's permission using my C-code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no such thing as a flag to mark a file as hidden, there is a convention that files beginning with a dot (`.`) are hidden. So to make a file "hidden", rename it to start with a dot.